# Can you get a Func<T> (or similar) from a MethodInfo object?

Tags: .net, performance, reflection, methodinfo, func

I realize that, generally speaking, there are performance implications of using reflection. (I myself am not a fan of reflection at all, actually; this is a purely academic question.)

Suppose there exists some class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string GetName() {
        return "My Name";
    }
}
```

Bear with me here. I know that if I have an instance of `MyClass` called `x`, I can call `x.GetName()`. Furthermore, I could set a `Func<string>` variable to `x.GetName`.

Now here's my question. Let's say I *don't* know the above class is called `MyClass`; I've got some object, `x`, but I have no idea what it is. I could check to see if that object has a `GetName` method by doing this:

```
MethodInfo getName = x.GetType().GetMethod("GetName");
```

Suppose `getName` is not null. Then couldn't I furthermore check if `getName.ReturnType == typeof(string)` and `getName.GetParameters().Length == 0`, and at this point, wouldn't I be quite certain that the method represented by my `getName` object could *definitely* be cast to a `Func<string>`, somehow?

I realize there's a `MethodInfo.Invoke`, and I also realize I could always *create* a `Func<string>` like:

```
Func<string> getNameFunc = () => getName.Invoke(x, null);
```

I guess what I'm asking is if there's any way to go **from** a `MethodInfo` object **to** the actual method it represents, incurring the performance cost of reflection in the *process*, but *after* that point being able to call the method directly (via, e.g., a `Func<string>` or something similar) *without* a performance penalty.

What I'm envisioning might look something like this:

```
// obviously this would throw an exception if GetActualInstanceMethod returned
// something that couldn't be cast to a Func<string>
Func<string> getNameFunc = (Func<string>)getName.GetActualInstanceMethod(x);
```

(I realize that doesn't exist; I'm wondering if there's anything *like* it.)

Comment: On the comments you make in your edit - you will see a huge speed increase with solutions like this, because there's very little difference between a dynamically compiled delegate and a statically compiled one; once the overhead of the compilation is factored out.

Since I 'discovered' the expression trees stuff, I've been using them all over the place, and would probably put it as my #1 feature from .Net 3.5 . In v4 it's even better as you can write multi-statement code - needed because of the extensions required by the DLR.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This kind of replaces my previous answer because this, although it's a slightly longer route - gives you a quick method call and, unlike some of the other answers, allows you to pass through different instances (in case you're going to encounter multiple instances of the same type).  IF you don't want that, check my update at the bottom (or look at Ben M's answer).

Here's a test method that does what you want:

```
public class TestType
{
  public string GetName() { return "hello world!"; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
  object o = new TestType();

  var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "input");
  var method = o.GetType().GetMethod("GetName", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
  //you should check for null *and* make sure the return type is string here.
  Assert.IsFalse(method == null && !method.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(string)));

  //now build a dynamic bit of code that does this:
  //(object o) => ((TestType)o).GetName();
  Func<object, string> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, string>>(
    Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(input, o.GetType()), method), input).Compile();

  string str = result(o);
  Assert.AreEqual("hello world!", str);
}
```

Once you build the delegate once - you can cache it in a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>> _methods;
```

All you do then is add it to the dictionary, using the incoming object's Type (from GetType()) as the key.  In the future, you first check to see if you have a ready-baked delegate in the dictionary (and invoke it if so), otherwise you build it first, add it in, and then invoke it.

Incidentally, this is a very highly simplified version of the kind of thing that the DLR does for it's dynamic dispatch mechanism (in C# terms, that's when you use the 'dynamic' keyword).

**And finally**

If, as a few people have mentioned, you simply want to bake a Func bound directly to the object you receive then you do this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{
  object o = new TestType();

  var method = o.GetType().GetMethod("GetName", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

  Assert.IsFalse(method == null && !method.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(string)));

  //this time, we bake Expression.Constant(o) in.
  Func<string> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(
   Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(o), method)).Compile();

  string str = result(); //no parameter this time.
  Assert.AreEqual("hello world!", str);
}
```

<strike>Note, though, that once the expression tree gets thrown away, you need to make sure that the `o` stays in scope, otherwise you could get some nasty results.  The easiest way would be to hold on to a local reference (in a class instance, perhaps) for the lifetime of your delegate.</strike> (Removed as a result of Ben M's comments)

Comment: Great minds think alike. :-) One question, though - why the cast expression?

Comment: Oh, but hold on - he still has to pass in a parameter to your lambda expression. I took from the original question that the generated function should be bound to the instance without having to pass a parameter.

Comment: You need the cast expression because we're defining the input parameter of the expression as 'object' and if you try to invoke the methodinfo via a reference to object it'll blow with: 
System.ArgumentException: Method 'System.String GetName()' declared on type 'TestProject1.UnitTest1+TestType' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Object'

Comment: have added example of how to generate a delegate bound to the instance so that no parameters need to be passed.

Comment: One note to your revision: `result` is in fact a delegate targeting an instance of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExecutionScope`, whose `Globals` property contains a reference to the original object (`o`) -- so there's no need to keep a second reference to avoid the garbage collector.

Comment: That's a comforting thing to know for some of the other code I've written that does this kind of thing (although I must confess - I've never bothered managing the lifetime of the instances... at least I know now I didn't need to!)

Comment: I was torn between accepting this or Ben M's answer since both were extremely helpful. In the end, it looks like you posted this one just a bit earlier, so I gave it to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - it's a tough choice when you ask the question and are presented with two good answers!  Thanks - glad to be of help.

Comment: If you want to cache static copies of the resulting constructed `Func`, instead of using a `Dictionary` you can follow the pattern of using a nested generic static class as in [Marc Gravell's answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4411203/57611).

Comment: you can - unless the code you're writing needs to invoke based on the result of GetType().  If I need to support both, I use a dictionary - but I agree, if you can guarantee compile-time type safety the nested generic works beautifully.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, that's possible:

```
Func<string> func = (Func<string>)
                     Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), getName);
```

Comment: This answer is not instance sensitive

Comment: @Ben M - Exactly what I was thinking - and why I decided to abandon the Delegate.CreateDelegate operation - because there'll be no way to pass the correct parameter type for the first parameter either.

Comment: Fair points. However, I don't think your solution is necessarily better. If you end up calling your dynamically compiled one on many different instances, the large cost of compilation for every instance may very well be more expensive than simply invoking the `MethodInfo`. If so, performance-wise you're better off making GetName be static and that takes a reference to the instance (so an explicit `this` pointer) resulting in a `Func<Foo, string`. Basically: it depends, YMMV.

Comment: Which is why my solution also includes one which allows you to pass in the instance because, obviously, closing a dynamic method over a particular instance is only ever going to hurt performance.  However, I didn't recommend this to the OP as it's up to him to make that choice.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my answer, by building an expression tree. Unlike the other answers, the result (`getNameFunc`) is a function that is bound to the original instance - without having to pass it in as a parameter.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var getNameFunc = GetStringReturningFunc(p, "GetName");
        var name = getNameFunc();
        Debug.Assert(name == p.GetName());
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Bob";
    }

    static Func<string> GetStringReturningFunc(object x, string methodName)
    {
        var methodInfo = x.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

        if (methodInfo == null ||
            methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(string) ||
            methodInfo.GetParameters().Length != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var xRef = Expression.Constant(x);
        var callRef = Expression.Call(xRef, methodInfo);
        var lambda = (Expression<Func<string>>)Expression.Lambda(callRef);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - a console app, not a test proj... better copy/paste value there!

Comment: Awesome answer, taught me a lot (hadn't done much work with expression trees previously). I gave it to Andras since his answer came a bit earlier, but this was really helpful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to do this is through `Delegate.CreateDelegate`:

```
Func<string> getNameFunc = (Func<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                                           typeof(Func<string>), x, getName);
```

Note that this binds `getNameFunc` to `x`, so for each `x` you'd need to create a new delegate instance. This option is a lot less complicated than the `Expression`-based examples. However, with the Expression-based examples, it's possible to create a `Func<MyClass, string> getNameFuncForAny` once, which you can reuse for each instance of a `MyClass`.

To create such a getNameFuncForAny, you'd need a method like

```
public Func<MyClass, string> GetInstanceMethod(MethodInfo method)
{
    ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "it");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, string>>(
        Expression.Call(x, method), x).Compile();
}
```

which you can use like so:

```
Func<MyClass, string> getNameFuncForAny = GetInstanceMethod(getName);

MyClass x1 = new MyClass();
MyClass x2 = new MyClass();

string result1 = getNameFuncForAny(x1);
string result2 = getNameFuncForAny(x2);
```

If you don't want to be tied to `Func<MyClass, string>`, you can define

```
public TDelegate GetParameterlessInstanceMethod<TDelegate>(MethodInfo method)
{
    ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(method.ReflectedType, "it");
    return Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(
        Expression.Call(x, method), x).Compile();
}
```

Comment: One could also `Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof (Func<MyClass, string>), getName)` -- I believe it's called an "open delegate".

Answer (score 1):

You could build an Expression Tree representing a lambda calling this method and then `Compile()` it so that further calls will just be as fast as standard compiled calls.

Alternatively, I wrote [this method](http://pastebin.org/288999) a good while ago based on a great MSDN article, which generates a wrapper using IL to call any `MethodInfo` way faster than with `MethodInfo.DynamicInvoke` since once the code is generated, there are almost no overhead over a normal call.

Answer (score 0):

One off the top of my head approach would be to use dynamic. You could then so something like this:

```
if( /* This method can be a Func<string> */)
{
    dynamic methodCall = myObject;
    string response = methodCall.GetName();
}
```