# How to create an instance of a generic type argument using a parameterized constructor in C#

Tags: c#, generics, exception

I'm trying to write a helper method that would log a message and throw an exception of a specified type with the same message. I have the following:

```
private void LogAndThrow<TException>(string message, params object[] args) where TException : Exception, new()
{
    message = string.Format(message, args);
    Logger.Error(message);
    throw new TException(message);
}
```

Before adding the `new()` constraint the compiler complained that without it I can't instantiate `TException`. Now the error message I get is "Cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a type parameter 'TException'". I tried creating the instance with the parameterless constructor and then set the `Message` property but it's read-only.

Is this a limitation of the language or is there a solution I don't know about? Maybe I could use reflection but that's overkill for such a simple task. (And pretty ugly, but that's a matter of personal opinion.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) (which allows you to pass in arguments) to create an instance of `TException`. Then, you could throw the created `TException`.

For example:

```
private void LogAndThrow<TException>(string message, params object[] args) where TException : Exception, new()
{
    message = string.Format(message, args);
    Logger.Error(message);

    TException exception = (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException), message);
    throw exception;
}
```

Comment: I marked this as accepted because JaredPar's solution may be faster but this one wraps the hackery inside the method and is more elegant from the caller's point of view.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is a limitation; there is no language construct for that.

My recommendation in this case would be to create a **typed** delegate to the constructor per-type; cache that delegate (usually in a static field of a generic type, for convenience) and re-use it. I can provide an example later - but I can't do it from iPod ;)

I *believe* I committed some code for this into Jon Skeet's MiscUtil library; so you could look there too.

---

As requested (comments), here is a way of doing this - in this case using the `Expression` API. Note in particular the use of the nested generic classes that ensure we do the reflection / compilation at most once per type-combination:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var ctor = TypeFactory.GetCtor<int, string, DemoType>();

        var obj = ctor(123, "abc");
        Console.WriteLine(obj.I);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.S);
    }
}

class DemoType {
    public int I { get; private set; }
    public string S { get; private set; }
    public DemoType(int i, string s) {
        I = i; S = s;
    }
}

static class TypeFactory {
    public static Func<T> GetCtor<T>() { return Cache<T>.func; }
    public static Func<TArg1, T> GetCtor<TArg1, T>() { return Cache<T, TArg1>.func; }
    public static Func<TArg1, TArg2, T> GetCtor<TArg1, TArg2, T>() { return Cache<T, TArg1, TArg2>.func; }
    private static Delegate CreateConstructor(Type type, params Type[] args) {
        if(type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if(args ==  null) args = Type.EmptyTypes;
        ParameterExpression[] @params = Array.ConvertAll(args, Expression.Parameter);
        return Expression.Lambda(Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(args), @params), @params).Compile();

    }
    private static class Cache<T> {
        public static readonly Func<T> func = (Func<T>)TypeFactory.CreateConstructor(typeof(T));
    }
    private static class Cache<T, TArg1> {
        public static readonly Func<TArg1, T> func = (Func<TArg1, T>)TypeFactory.CreateConstructor(typeof(T), typeof(TArg1));
    }
    private static class Cache<T, TArg1, TArg2> {
        public static readonly Func<TArg1, TArg2, T> func = (Func<TArg1, TArg2, T>)TypeFactory.CreateConstructor(typeof(T), typeof(TArg1), typeof(TArg2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you would do it? It sounds very interesting.

Comment: @neo2862 probably via the Expression API - I'll be at a PC in about 2 hours; will post then

Comment: This is amazing. Especially how you use static fields of the constructed nested types for caching. I would upvote it 10 times if I could.

Comment: @neo2862 - that also provides guaranteed thread safety, which is nice ;p

Comment: How does this compare to use cases where one can just do `System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2, param3)`? Is there benefit in caching the exact constructor this finds?

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of the generic constraint `new`.  It can only be used to create objects through the parameterless constructor.

One way to work around this is to provide a lambda factory method which takes the appropriate parameters.  At the call site it can defer to the class constructor

```
private void LogAndThrow<TException>(
  Func<string,TException> func, 
  string message, 
  params object[] args) where TException : Exception {     

  message = string.Format(message, args);     
  Logger.Error(message);   
  throw func(message);
}

LogAndThrow(msg => new InvalidOperationException(msg), "my message");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void ThrowAndLog<TException>(string message, params object[] args) 
    where TException : Exception, new()
{
    message = string.Format(message, args);
    Logger.Error(message);
    throw (TException)typeof(TException).GetConstructor(
        new[] { typeof(string) }).Invoke(new object[] { message });
}
```

Comment: Generic is for speed up runtime, not doing runtime creation.