# How to Get Reference to Method from MethodInfo (C#)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to build a dictionary that indexes each static method in a class so they can be looked up with a string. I can't seem to find a way to actually get a reference back to the method from the MethodInfo. Is this possible?

```
delegate void SkillEffect(BattleActor actor, BattleActor target);

public static class SkillEffectLookup
{
    public static Dictionary<string, SkillEffect> lookup;

    public static void Build()
    {
        lookup = new Dictionary<string, SkillEffect>();
        Type type = typeof(SkillEffects);
        var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methods)
        {
            lookup.Add(methodInfo.Name, _____________);
        }
    }

public static class SkillEffects
{
    public static Attack(BattleActor actor, BattleActor target)
    {
        // Do Things
    }

    public static NonAttack(BattleActor actor, BattleActor target)
    {
        // Do Other Things
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` method. With that you can create and store the delegate to the methods using your `MethodInfo`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you get a Func<T> (or similar) from a MethodInfo object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933221/can-you-get-a-funct-or-similar-from-a-methodinfo-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use CreateDelegate method. It will work only if you know method`s signature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx

**UPD** (tnx to Chris Sinclair):

example of using

```
lookup.Add(methodInfo.Name
      , (SkillEffect)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SkillEffect), methodInfo));
```

Comment: Maybe add the relevant line of code ustor is asking for: `lookup.Add(methodInfo.Name, (SkillEffect)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SkillEffect), methodInfo));`

Answer (score 2):

from the code it would seem you are looking for a delegate rather than a reference to a method. (Which does not really exist in C#)

I would change the dictionary to `Dictionary<string,Func<BattleActor,BattleActor> lookup`
though this is a matter of personal preference and unrelated to your issue. (You can substitute `Func<BattletActor,BattlActor>` with `SkillEffect` in the below code)

and then do

```
Func<BattleActor,BattleActor> func = (Func<BattleActor,BattleActor>)
                     Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<BattleActor,BattleActor>), methodInfo);

lookup.Add(methodInfo.Name,func);
```

A functor is a delegate and can be invoked just like any other delegate

```
 lookup["mymethod"](actor,target);
```

you could see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933221/can-you-get-a-funct-or-similar-from-a-methodinfo-object) for more information

Comment: He's already doing this, only he's explicitly defined the delegate at the top of the code rather than using `Func`: `delegate void SkillEffect(BattleActor actor, BattleActor target);`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair He's not creating a delegate which is the key.

Comment: Yeah, but why not leverage the existing delegate he has instead of throwing `Func<BattleActor, BattleActor>` into the mix?

Answer (score 0):

MethodInfo is the metadata for the method. To actually invoke the method you call (surprise!) MethodInfo.Invoke.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to save a reference to the method itself so you can call it, I don't think you can. Really what you do is call it via the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k9x6bc0.aspx) method on the `MethodInfo`:

```
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methods)
        {
            lookup.Add(methodInfo.Name, _____________);
        }
```

And then to call it:

```
lookup[methodName].Invoke(null, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, args, null);
```

Comment: Well technically there's no function point in C# (unless you get fancy with unsafe code) so no you can't but I think OP is actually talking about delegates and you can create delegates from MethodInfo objects