# How to add an event dynamically by its name

Tags: c#

> I have `Delegate` type and `function` in string format.  how can i add
>   that function in the `delegate`?

Datatable Events;

```
/* Having Records

Control Events      MethodName
ControlName     Validating      Leave       Enter
TextBox1        Textbox1_Validating TextBox1_Leave  --

*/

foreach(DataRow Row in Events.Rows)
{
    if (Row["Validating"].ToString() != "")
    {
//Here is I need a help that how can i add Textbox1_Validating event in 
//TextBox1.Validating
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code so far

Comment: You're trying to call a delegate? Or are you trying to call a method on an object? Or maybe you're trying to raise an event? Be much clearer on **exactly** what you need please.

Comment: Instead of infinitely begging users for improvements in their incomplete questions, I'd suggest to simply close them and save rubbish questions on SO. It's not difficult to find resoruces to learn how to ask minimally decent questions! p.s. Quality question cares about English syntax too, so "I", not "i". Don't be lazy!

Comment: Actually i am having the event in string form like "TextBox1_Validating" and it was declared too but now i want to add this method to the textbox1.Validating Event on runtime. 
Then how can i add this "TextBox1_Validating" in textbox1.Validating event.

Comment: @AliasgerSW: your comment should be part of the question.

Comment: Please check my question once again. I need it urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the [Delegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9tz542wy.aspx) overloads to achieve this. But you need to know the target object (the object, which contains the method you want to get called when the event raises)

An example (pseudo code):

```
public void TextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs args)
{
    // handle the event
}


public void RegisterEvent()
{
    CancelEventHandler handler = (CancelEventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(CancelEventHandler), 
        this,
        "TextBox1_Validating");
    textBox1.Validating += handler;
}
```

You can also read this MSDN article, which shows some other ways: [How to: Hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx)

Comment: thnx Stephan, you take me out of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some naive implementation is to use another level of indirection when calling `MethodIndo` from lambda and assign it to delegate instance of type `Func<int, string>`. Note that there exist more complex delegate conversions:

```
void Main()
{
    string methodName = "SomeMethod";

    var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

    Action<string> myFunc = str => methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[]{str});

    MyEvent += myFunc;

    MyEvent("value");

}
public event Action<string> MyEvent = delegate{}; 
                                    //default so that not to check for null

public void SomeMethod(string val)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("event called with: " + val);
}
```

prints

```
event called with: value
```

Consider another [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933221/can-you-get-a-funct-or-similar-from-a-methodinfo-object) about this topic. It really hard to tell what you want to achieve, but I think you can use this implementation as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is a type that safely encapsulates a method, similar to a function pointer in C and C++. Unlike C function pointers, delegates are object

for more information you can refer [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx)