# How to access to an exact method group expression using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know how to get MethodInfo for a particular method, and also know how to call that method via reflection. However I could not figure out the following:

I have the assignment statement below:

```
Func<double, double> myFunc = Math.Sqrt;
```

I would like to get the **exact** same content for the myFunc variable via reflection, having the MethodInfo for Math.Sqrt in hand. Unfortunately building wrapper lambdas or Expression around the MethodInfo is not satisfying. I would like something like this:

```
Func<double, double> myFunc = GetMethodGroupFor(methodInfoForMathSqrt);
```

In case if the isolated sample does not explains what I would like to really do here is a bit more explanation:

I have to fill a `Dictionary<string, Func<double, double>>`with 100s of method "keys" and delegates. Like:

```
myDictionary.Add("mykey", Math.Sqrt);
```

However I would not like to do this by 100s of assignment statement, instead I would like get the 100s of appropriate MethodInfos via reflection then in a for cycle fill the dictionary.

Is this possible?

Comment: so, you want get `MethodInfo` and save it in variable with type like `Func<double, double>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get a Func<T> (or similar) from a MethodInfo object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933221/can-you-get-a-funct-or-similar-from-a-methodinfo-object)

Comment: I would like to have the exact same content of the myFunc variable like in the code sample. I would like to do this via reflection

Comment: see duplicated question

Comment: Yes I've read it and the answers. Unfortunately the _similar_ is not suitable for me. (please see the similar word in that title). I've also have ideas about creating delegates and expressions, but that is unfortunately not satisfying....

Comment: so, what you really want and have? you provide some statement, but not explain what you get by reflection and what you get at end

Comment: I think I've explained why the referred "duplicate" is not a duplicate both in comments and both in the edited question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93950/discussion-between-grundy-and-g-pickardou).

Comment: With reflection you've got access to the name of those methods, and you can create delegates from method-info's via `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, so yes, this is perfectly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you'll be using reflection to look for methods that match a particular signature as following:

```
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = typeof(Math).GetMethods()
    .Where(method =>
    {
        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(double))
            return false;

        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
        return parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(double);
    });
```

From there, you can fill your dictionary as following:

```
var methodLookup = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double>>();
foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
{
    var name = method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + method.Name;
    var d = (Func<double, double>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<double, double>), method);
    methodLookup[name] = d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The line d  = (...) would be enough :-).