# How to order classes by inheritence?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, reflection

I'm using reflection to retrieve a list of available classes and I want to adapt the input object to the most ***specific*** class that matches; i.e. I want to do something like:

```
RawData input = new RawData() { ... };
Type targetAdapter = AdapterSelector.SelectAdapterFor(input);
AdapterSelector.TryGetAdaptMethod(targetAdapter, out Func<RawData, Adapter> fAdapt);
Adapter adapted = fAdapt(input);
```

Each applicable class has the following signature:

```
public class Adapter
{
    public static Adapter Adapt(RawData input) { ... }
    public static bool Matches(RawData input) { ... }
}
```

Retrieving the list of classes with the required methods can be done as follows using reflection<sup>1</sup>:

```
public partial class AdapterSelector
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetApplicableAdapterTypes()
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> allTypes = typeof(AdapterSelector).Assembly.GetTypes();
        IEnumerable<Type> applicableTypes = from t in allTypes
                                            where TryGetAdaptMethod(t, _) &&
                                                  TryGetMatchMethod(t, _)
                                            select t;
        return applicableTypes;
    }

    private static bool TryGetAdaptMethod(Type type, out Func<RawData, Adapter> adapt)
    {
        MethodInfo adaptMethod = type.GetMethod("Adapt", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(RawData) }, null);
        if (adaptMethod != null)
        {
            adapt = (Func<RawData, Adapter>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<RawData, Adapter>), null, adapterMethod);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            adapt = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool TryGetMatchMethod(Type type, out Func<RawData, bool> match)
    {
        MethodInfo matchMethod = type.GetMethod("Match", BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(RawData) }, null);
        if (matchMethod != null)
        {
            match = (Func<RawData, bool>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<RawData, bool>), null, matchMethod);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            match = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that I could use the following [`IComparer<Type>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) to order this list of adapters:

```
public class TypeHierarchyComparer: IComparer<Type>
{
    public int Compare(Type lhs, Type rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.IsSubclassOf(lhs))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (lhs.IsSubclassOf(rhs))
        {
            return +1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Return arbitrary but fixed value for siblings, cousins, etc.
            return lhs.FullName.CompareTo(rhs.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is intended to be a partial ordering: if one type is a subclass of the other that type should be ordered after<sup>2</sup> the latter.  If neither type is a subclass of the other, the order is undefined.

With this ordering I hoped that the following hierarchy of adapters would be sorted correctly<sup>3</sup>:

- `Adapter`

  - `N`
  - `F`
  - `H`
  - `I`
  - `K`

    - `E`
    - `G`
    - `L`
    - `M`
    - `Q`
    - `R`
  - `O`
  - `B`
  - `C`
  - `J`
  - `P`

    - `AA`
    - `AB`
    - `D`
    - `S`
    - `T`

However, the results of:

AdapterSelector.GetApplicableAdapterTypes().OrderBy((x) => x, new TypeHierarchyComparer());

are:

`Adapter`, `AA`, `AB`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `N`, `F`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `P`, `E`, `G`, `L`, `M`, `O`, `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`

Is the correct order `O` and `P` should be ordered before `AA`, `AB`, `D`, `S`, and `T` and `O` should be before `B`, `C`, and `J`.  It appears that subclasses are ordered after one of their parents but not necessarily after all their parents.

How can I sort classes by specificity? (I.e. ordering the subclasses before/after all their parents)

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>See [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Type.GetMethod(string, BindingFlags, Binder, Type[], ParameterModifier[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fed8f59(v=vs.110).aspx), [Can you get a Func<T> (or similar) from a MethodInfo object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933221/814206), and [`Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, object, methodInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551(v=vs.110).aspx)</sub>

<sup>2)</sup> <sub>I'm using [`Enumerable.OrderByDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IComparer<TKey>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the matcher to apply first in the front of the list.</sub>

<sup>3)</sup> <sub>The class hierarchy as shown by Visual Studio's Solution Explorer.  I cannot disclose the names of the adapters, therefore I used `AA` to `T`, I preserved the alphabetical order of the names.</sub>

Comment: The error you are getting is when you compare E & F.  E is level one while F is level 2.  I would recommend adding a level number to the class so you are only comparing the names at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your arbitrary sorting rule is too arbitrary.

Rather than sorting on type names (so, comparing `G` and `B`, would say that `G` should come after `B`), you should instead find the closest common ancestor of two unrelated types. Then, you should apply sorting based on the immediate descendent of the common ancestor through which the two types descend.

So, for comparing `G` and `B`, you find the closest common ancestor (`Adapter`), and then find the types through which these two types are descended (`K` and `B`) and then perform your arbitrary sorting rule on *those* types.

---

Something like this (no promises about code quality :-)):

```
    public List<Type> Ancestors(Type any)
    {
        var result = new List<Type>();
        result.Add(any);
        while (any != typeof(object))
        {
            any = any.BaseType;
            result.Insert(0, any);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public int Compare(Type lhs, Type rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.IsSubclassOf(lhs))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (lhs.IsSubclassOf(rhs))
        {
            return +1;
        }
        else
        {
            var lAncs = Ancestors(lhs);
            var rAncs = Ancestors(rhs);
            int ix = 0;
            while (lAncs[ix] == rAncs[ix])
            {
                ix++;
            }
            return lAncs[ix].FullName.CompareTo(rAncs[ix].FullName);
        }
    }
```

I think this code is safe from wandering off of the end of the lists since if one of the lists is exhausted, it means that one of the types *is* in fact an ancestor of the other so the previous subclassing rules should have already resolved the comparison.

Also, you may wish to consider "memoizing" the Ancestors lookup using a `Dictionary<Type,List<Type>>`.

Comment: Bad idea. You're not going to make the relation transitive by hacks like this. There are sorting algorithms specifically designed for partial orderings.

Comment: ...and even if you happen to make the relation transitive, as I admit your hack appears to do, you have to prove it, and what's the point? Just use a topological sort.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy - does it help if you realise that what's being done above is  roughly equivalent to replacing each sort key with a string containing its entire hierarchical path (e.g. replace `E` with `o->Adapter->K->E`) and then sorting on those strings? Finding the ancestor and the immediate derivatives is just equivalent to jumping to the point at which we know that the keys start to differ.

Comment: I'd already realized that, which is why I'd added the second comment above. If you talk about these strings, the proof that the resulting relation is a complete ordering becomes obvious enough that it need not be spelled out. My point is, you can't extend any partial-order relation to a complete order (imagine a commit DAG with merges), there is a class of sorting algorithms specifically designed for partial orderings, so why not use them and learn something new? BTW now there are two things to learn in this question: topological sorting and extending a partial order to a complete order.

Comment: Or, rather, at least for a finite set a partial order *can* be extended to a complete order, but (a) it may not be obvious how to do it correctly - that's what happened in the question - and (b) the resulting order might not "make sense" in the framework of the partial order. For example, with commit DAGs, define a partial order "compatible with" where a child revision is compatible with parent revision(s). It can be extended to a complete order, but then two revisions on separate branches will be `<` or `>` when they aren't compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting algorithms used by Linq `OrderBy` (quick-sort) require a complete order relation. You have extended your partial order with an arbitrary assignment on pairs not ordered by your partial order relation, but the result isn't going to fulfil the axioms of complete ordering, in particular it's not going to be transitive (e.g. in your toy example `P<AA` and `AA<E`, but `E<P` when transitivity requires `P<E`) and the sorting algorithms that rely on transitivity will behave arbitrarily badly. That's what you observe. Instead of `OrderBy` which uses quick sort internally, you want a topological sorting algorithm.